# Electrical issue

Tags: electrical

I was changing out some switches etc in a residential property. As usual, the circuit board is badly labelled. So, I changed two 3 way switches that both operate a different set of led lights in the same area and allegedly both are on the same circuit. I accidentally touched the ground on a live wire after I had pushed the wires into the box and turned on the power which tripped the circuit breaker. I discovered the short and rectified it. When I turned on the power, one set of lights worked, but the other lights did not. There is only one hot red wire amongst both switches. Have I wired them up wrong somehow? I copied the wiring from the old switches. I also tried powering the now defunct switch with the hot red wire and the lights worked, so not a bulb issue.

Comment: Disconnect the switches and test them separately, to see if you have damaged them. If they switch continuity as expected then you have indeed wired them up wrong somehow.

Comment: It's difficult but possible for us to analyze your circuits remotely. You have to supply more details until you have posted a complete description. Photos or diagrams can be helpful.

Comment: Sometimes photographs of the insides of the junction boxes can add vital information. Good photos are hard to make because you have to physically separate the wires, and show the backs of the switches.

Comment: Please post a wiring diagram (like you drew) , and a picture of each box with the switches showing how the wiring is connected. From what your writing is - perhaps you burnt up a switch ?? You put an old one in and it worked tells me - you burnt up a new one ...

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri you could have wrote those comments all in one comment.

Comment: @Ken: I have discovered that if I ask several questions in one comment, in many cases the OP will answer only the first question.